# PyQt application getting stuck on Raspberry pi while running multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, pyqt, raspberry-pi, qthread

I have created a `PyQt` based application running on raspberry pi which takes input from sensors. The application was running perfectly before adding threads, but now while running the application it gets stuck at different interfaces. I am using `QThreads`. Can anybody help?

Thanks.

Comment: Not without some code. Do you have any kind of locks in your code?

Comment: Your question is broad and unclear, show us your code.

Comment: For you to ask a good question read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask